# Using JS to change three div IDs (carousel-esque), works twice, but then skips a div

Tags: javascript, carousel, z-index

I'm trying to create a carousel where all three items are visible, and they switch position when the navigation is clicked (at the moment only working on the left arrow).

I am doing this by assigning each div to a position using an id, and using JS to change the ids.

It works as intended, but when #pos3 (the banana) becomes #pos1, it for some reason gets skipped, and #pos2 and #pos3 just exchange places.

**The CSS:**

```
#pos1{
left:10%;
}

#pos2{
left:30%;
z-index:2;
top:50px;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

#pos3{
left:60%;
}
```

**The JS**

```
document.getElementById("left").onclick = function (){
  document.getElementById("pos2").setAttribute("id", "pos1");
  document.getElementById("pos3").setAttribute("id", "pos2");  
  document.getElementById("pos1").setAttribute("id", "pos3");    
};
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ey13h5c4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> document.getElementById("pos2").setAttribute("id", "pos1");
>   document.getElementById("pos3").setAttribute("id", "pos2");
>   document.getElementById("pos1").setAttribute("id", "pos3");

By the time third line is executed, pos1 doesn't exist as you've already changed that on 1st line.

Simply introduce a temporary id to fix this.

> document.getElementById("pos1").setAttribute("id", "temp");
>   document.getElementById("pos2").setAttribute("id", "pos1");
>   document.getElementById("pos3").setAttribute("id", "pos2");
>   document.getElementById("temp").setAttribute("id", "pos3");

Comment: Thanks! Just figured this out above but giving you the green check anyway

Answer (score 0):

Without testing it myself, it looks like when you change `#pos2` to `#pos1`, you end up with 2 elements with the id `#pos1`, because the original `#pos1` has not yet been changed to `#pos3`. So, when the code gets to the point where it's changing `#pos1` to `#pos3`, it's changing *both* elements, leaving you without a `#pos1`.

Comment: Ah I knew it was something like that, just didn't quite get there.  Thank you!  Is there a way to change both simultaneously?  Did I approach this in the wrong way to begin with?

Comment: Possibly. I personally don't like changing ids. An id, Symantecally, should identify a single element, so really shouldn't change. You're better to use classes I think, and maybe use ids saved somehow to manage the position of each element.

Comment: Figured it out -

Adding a #pos4 "holding position" which is the same as #pos1 and then switching them at the end of the function makes it loop.  The animation is not quite right but that can be fixed -  for the moment I've accomplished what I set out to do.  Thanks!